# What kind of URL is this?

Tags: uri, credentials, http-authentication

Someone give me this link with username and password, told me to deploy the war file to it. 
How to access this kind of link?

```
less@adz.rick.com:/apps/less/pf/service-5000-tomcat8
```

Thank you

Comment: I guess this is <user name>@<server name>:<path>

Comment: It's a deprecated way to send credentials ( `http://login:password@mywebsite.com/`). See [RFC 3986 §3.2.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for the deprecation reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, this is `user@server:path` and could be used for HTTP authentication (which is deprecated, as mentioned in the comments, too). But also, this is how SSH paths look like, which is likely to be the case.

SSH is bound to a user on a machine and if I am not totally mistaken, you are asked to deploy your application as user `less` on the machine `adz.rick.com` to the path `/apps/less/pf/service-5000-tomcat8`.

If so, you should be able SSH to that machine (which would require you to have your public SSH key stored there or you need to authenticate with a password), use scp or rsync to send your files there or whatever way you prefer to use SSH.

EDIT:

To avoid any confusion that may arise from the second paragraph, saying you have to do *this* as *that* user on *that* machine, a common rsync command to send files to that exact location would be

```
rsync -avhP /my/local/service/path less@adz.rick.com:/apps/less/pf/service-5000-tomcat8
```

You see, the full path as you posted in your question is used as the second parameter to rsync, being its target path.

Comment: Indeed it makes sense to interpret it as part of an SSH URI (I also add the URI tag btw)